# Import CSV to MySQL and convert date (on multiple columns)

Tags: mysql, date, csv

I realise there are a heap of posts on this topic, but I haven't been able to find one that deals with importing data that have multiple date columns that need to be converted.

My columns are as follows, the ones in bold are date columns;

(**date**, symbol, under, **expiration**, strike, put_call, bid, ask, price, volume, open_interest, implied_vol, delta, gamma, theta, vega, nonstd)

I have been able to successfully convert one of the date columns, but I can not seem to do both simultaneously.

The code I have been trying to use is as follows.

Note the two set statements at the bottom. Any idea why the expiration one doesn't work? It just shows in a black color in SQL compared to a light blue for date.

Thanks

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'A:\\My Files\\Desktop\\SPX\\test.csv'
INTO TABLE spx_options_data2 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@date, symbol, under, @expiration, strike, put_call, bid, ask, price, volume, open_interest, implied_vol, delta, gamma, theta, vega, nonstd)
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d/%m/%Y')
SET expiration = STR_TO_DATE(@expiration, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: `set date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d/%m/%Y'), expiration = ...`

Comment: Thanks all, that did the trick Solarflare! Thanking you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as @Solarflares correction I get a warning on a second date field if my date fields in the csv file are enclosed by ". Commenting out the escaped by clause fixed that issue.  I would be also suspicious about the word date in the Set statement.